# Data migration over WAN

Tags: migration, datacenter

I have 50 GB on servers in switzerland, that need to be copied over our wan connection. After the data is migrated we'll switch the users to our newer server based computing solution.

The only problem is that it's live data. So I was wondering if there is a way to copy the 40 GB before the migration, and just before we go live make a differential copy.

How would you guys approach this?

Is there a free way to accomplish this?

The data I'm talking about are user documents and company data.

Thanks

Comment: What OSs are on the servers?  How fast is the WAN link?  What's the daily data change rate look like?  Are there any windows where you can take the systems offline?

Comment: The OS is windows server 2003 R2 Enterprise. The WAN link is 2 Mb/ps

Comment: I have no idea about the data change rate. The only time we have to migrate data is at night,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is heavily dependent on the type of data (and to a lesser degree, the OS) you use, but [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) is a good start for copying files in general. For databases and similar file types, you might need to use another option, but again, this would be dependent on the type of database.

Comment: Beat me to it...I was going to suggest rsync the first pass, then rsync again to capture changed data and then again until everything is copied.

Answer (score 1):

> Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurtling down the highway. (Tanenbaum, Andrew S)

Yes - I'd go with restoring a backup at the new site, then unison/rsync to keep the data inline if its just files.

But this approach needs some work if we're talking about a database.

C.

Answer (score 0):

if your using linux you could also consider using drdb however performance might be degraded over your wan link.

http://www.drbd.org/